# In Python Flask, how to get the role name by the current logged in user?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have 3 tables for user-role many-to-many relationship in Flask. How should I get the role name from the current user?

In my models.py

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "Users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, server_default='')

    # Define the relationship to Role via UserRoles
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='UserRoles', backref=db.backref("user", lazy="dynamic"))


# Define the Role data-model
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', secondary='UserRoles', backref=db.backref("role", lazy="dynamic"))


# # Define the UserRoles association table
class UserRole(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'UserRoles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('Users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('Roles.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

In my views.py:

```
from flask_user import current_user

@app.route("/TestUserRole")
def user_role():
    role = current_user.role
    return str(role)
```

On the browser, it shows me the returned result:

```
SELECT [Roles].id AS [Roles_id], [Roles].name AS [Roles_name] FROM [Roles], [UserRoles] WHERE [UserRoles].user_id = ? AND [Roles].id = [UserRoles].role_id
```

Is there a possible way to show the role name of the current user, something like the following (bad example, though, since it will pop out error)?

```
role = current_user.role.name
```

Comment: Try `user_roles = [role.name for role in current_user.roles]`

Comment: Can you not do something like `Role.query.get(**current users role id**)`  and add this as an extra column? I'm new too :)

Answer (score 1):

The `current_user.has_roles` function will help.

It is quite simple: 
Suppose you have configure below roles like

Role1: Admin

Role2: Manager

If user has no role associated then, `current_user.has_roles()` will be False.

If logged in user has a role of 'Admin', this can be verified using `current_user.has_roles('Admin')`.

So users roles can be accessed via `has_roles()`.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but I'll comment on the solution in case anyone encounters the same problem.

```
roles = current_user.roles
list_roles = []
for role in roles:
    list_roles.append(role.name)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).